# Precision and recall in a multi-class classification system?

Tags: classification, precision-recall

Having looked at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall) and looked around here, I'm still not clear how to identify the true positives, true negatives, false positives and false negatives in the multi-label classification problem that I'm doing, so that I can calculate precision, recall and F-measure.

I have a few categories and a few hundred documents. Having trained an [SVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) to perform classification, I have the following data

```
document 1 | actual category, category assigned by SVM
document 2 | actual category, category assigned by SVM
...
document n | actual category, category assigned by SVM
```

The category assigned by the SVM is often the same as the actual category but not always. The true positives are when

```
actual category = category assigned by SVM
```

I guess false positives would be

```
actual category =/= category assigned by SVM
```

But I'm not sure about false positives or true negatives.

I feel like this may be a basic question but I can't find a clear (enough) example.

Comment: See also http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/63477/calculate-precision-and-recall/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For those who might be interested in an answer, this comes from a much more knowledgeable source than me (PhD candidate in NLP):

> When doing multiclass classification, precision and recall are really
>   only  properly defined for individual classes (you can average across
>   classes to  get a general scores for the entire system, but it's not
>   really that  useful; in my opinion, you're probably better off just
>   using overall  accuracy as your metric of performance).
>
> For an individual class, the false positives are those instances which
>   were classified as that class, but in fact aren't, and the true
>   negatives are those instances which are not that  class, and were
>   indeed classified as not belonging to that class  (regardless of
>   whether they were correctly classified).

Comment: Can you tell me about the PhD source of this information?
I need to bring sources to a project that I'm working on...

Comment: Saved me! "Regardless of whether they are correctly classified!" I was completely confused what is the correct definition of TN. Finally back to the program code! Thanks!